# File locking in windows & linux

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems, file-permissions

To what I've observed, Windows "locks" a file and prevents access (such as write and delete/remove access) when a particular file (such as a pdf) is opened as read-only.

How is this actually implemented under the hood?
Is this similar to how Linux handles files/file systems?
Would love to be pointed in some direction/given some useful keywords to start with. (Googling didn't help much)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking

Comment: Either this information is published and accessible to you as well as us, or it is not and we have no secret knowledge. Do you have a problem that needs to be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *is* actually called "file locking", and specifically "mandatory locking" when it prevents the actual read or write operations from being done.

(The other type is advisory locking, where cooperating processes have to explicitly check whether a lock is held before proceeding, but a non-cooperating process can still write anywhere it likes.)

Even *more* specifically, you're talking about a Windows feature called "sharing mode", which is something it inherited from LAN Manager in the MS-DOS era (i.e. back when PC software wasn't written with concurrency in mind, but still had to safely access a common SMB fileshare somehow). You can see it [documented here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/creating-and-opening-files) as a parameter to the CreateFile() API. Some more commentary [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040511-00/?p=39403).

Sharing mode is just a special case of mandatory locking. Due to its historical origins, the shareMode flags are reversed in that they must be provided to *allow* concurrent reads or writes (compared to typical file locking APIs, which are "opt-in" and temporarily *deny* concurrent access that would otherwise be allowed), but it still works in fundamentally the same way.

> Is this similar to how Linux handles files/file systems?

Mostly no. Linux doesn't have an equivalent to "share modes" (all access is allowed by default), and it doesn't even support mandatory locking in general, either.¹

But Linux does have *advisory* locking, i.e. the kind that only affects programs that explicitly call the locking functions such as flock() or fcntl(), and many programs use it everyday to coordinate e.g. SQLite database writes (take a look at the output of `sudo lslocks`).

¹ (Previously Linux did have mandatory locking as a hidden, disabled-by-default feature, but it was considered mostly unusable, and finally got removed in Linux 5.15. Enabling this feature would have allowed a program to use the same flock() to outright prevent other processes from opening the same file from reading or writing – a bit similar to how share flags work in Windows, although still opt-in rather than opt-out.)